# Using Raspberry pi as USB bridge

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi, printer, apple, ios

I would like to use my `raspberry pi` as a USB bridge between multiple devices. We can assume that I want to connect my iPad which has POS software on it to my thermal printer. Most of star or Epson thermal printers can be recognized by iOS since they have MFi certification (It doesn't mean they have to be AirPrint compatible because they are not, they can be detected when they will be connected to iOS by lightning cable.). I would like to put my Raspberry Pi in the middle and act as they cannot see there is a device between them so technically iOS will detect printer as usual. In this case, I wanted to use USB monitoring packages to see what is happening between iPad and printer in terms of transferring data. I would be very happy if you can share your experience and ideas on this subject.[image]

Comment: You'll probably have better luck getting advice in the raspberry-pi SE: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ voting to migrate this there.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [libusb](https://libusb.info). It'll send USB packets as network packets, and on the client (iPad, in your case), a driver will make it appear as of those packets come from a real USB device.

While OS X is among the supported platforms, I'm not sure if you can install the client directly on the iPad; you may have to root the iPad first.

If that is not possible, and if you need to connect the RaspPi via USB to the iPad, you'll need a RaspPi (or similar device) that has an USB OTG port which can act as an USB device towards the iPad (USB is not symmetrical).

There has been software like [USBproxy](https://github.com/dominicgs/USBProxy) which implements such a man-in-the-middle (MITM) function on a BeagleBone, but I don't know if it has been ported to a RaspPi.